# Glob to match all images in 2 directories?

Tags: regex, file, glob

I have two directories:

> files/imgs/

and

> files/imgs/subdir

I want to match all images in these directories i.e:

> files/imgs/*.{jpg,png,gif}

and

> files/imgs/subdir/*.{jpg,png,gif}

How would I go about doing this? I do not want to match all sub directories of imgs, only the specified 'subdir'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using bash, you could match using curly brackets:

`files/imgs/{subdir/,}*.{jpg,png,gif}`

Answer (score 0):

Regex can be specified in many different ways but regard to your specification I would do something like this:

```
/((subdir|imgs)\/[\w\d\s]+\.(ping|jpg|gif))/g
```

One way of thinking of regex is to think of your pattern backward (from right to left) instead of left to right. This will help you identify some pattern easier, but it not always the case so be flexible!
Also, it is good to use regex validation tools such as http://regexr.com/